FI-homology of a spectral sequence of rational FI-modules
Let $(E^r_{p,q})$ be a spectral sequence of rational $\mathsf{FI}$-modules. Call $H^{\mathsf{FI}}$ the $\mathsf{FI}$-homology (see here) and $t_k X= \deg H^{\text{FI}}_k X$ the $k$-th generation degree of an $\mathsf{FI}$-module $X$.
I would like to know if there exists some way to bound the generation degrees of the abutment knowing those of the initial page. It would suffice to understand the following situation :
let $F \xrightarrow{f} G \xrightarrow{g} H$ be a complex of $\mathsf{FI}$-modules, I want to understand the $t_k$s of $\ker g /\operatorname{im} f $ depending on those of $F,G,H$.  However, I don't know such a result concerning the $t_k$s.
In this article (lemma 6.3.2) it is shown that over $\mathbb Q$, if $F,G,H$ have stability degree $\leq r$ then the homology too. But I'm a bit confused about the logical relations between stability degree, the degrees $(t_k)$,the weight, and other quantities measuring some stability property of $\mathsf{FI}$-modules. Is there a way to obtain a bound for the $t_k$s by using some of these relations?

Check this paper of Eric Ramos https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.03964

Thank you ! I will look into that.

The work of Church-Ellenberg that you linked to bounds $t_k(M)$ in terms of $t_0(M)$ and $t_1(M)$.
This paper of Church-Reinhold-Miller-Nagpal introduces two invariants: the stable degree $\delta(M)$ and the local degree $h^{\rm max}(M)$.  These invariants can be used to bound $t_0(M)$ and $t_1(M)$ and conversely are bounded in terms $t_0(M)$ and $t_1(M)$ (see Proposition 3.1).  Furthermore, Proposition 3.3 of their paper bounds $\delta, h^{max}$ of a kernel/cokernel of a map of $FI$ modules in terms of the invariants of the domain and codomain.
Putting these bounds together with the work of Church-Ellenberg, you can get a bound on $t_i$ of the homology of a complex.  In CRMN's paper, they apply these invariants to several spectral sequences to establish stability ranges.

Great answer, thank you for your help !
